# Zuul filter to duplicate traffic

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

I would like to use Zuul to efficiently (asynchronously) route a copy of my traffic to a debug service for testing. I am new to Zuul and am looking through existing filter to find a neat way to do this but I haven't found a good example yet. Is there a built-in Zuul way to "copy" a request and forward it to a different host?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: for me that sounds more like messaging than a proxy

Comment: what did you end up doing for traffic mirroring/duplicating traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a built in way to copy a request.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!